# Matching partial strings in a phrase

Tags: ruby, regex

I put up an intranet site that loops through a .csv dump of our customer database and uses a form to help look up account numbers.

I want to treat all of my keywords as wild card terms, but respect their order. For example, if I have company `A`: `"The Monogramme Shoppe"` and company `B`: `"Monograms & More at The Shop"`, I want to return `A` and `B` options if I type `"mono shop"` in the form field. This code does that:

```
company_lookup = company_lookup.split(" ")

counter = company_lookup.length
company_lookup.each do |com|
  if company.downcase.include? com.downcase
    counter = counter - 1
  end
end
if counter == 0
  match_found = true
  account_number = row[2].to_s
  matches.push [account_number, company]
end
```

But if I type `"mono the"`, I also get both results. There, I only want to get the `B` result.

Is there any way to use regular expressions to, say look for `PartialKeyword1` and `PartialKeyword2` in a string and return `true` if matched?

Comment: It's difficult to help without knowing what `company_lookup`, `company` and `row` are.

Comment: Arie's answer below was exactly what I needed, but in case others need this to make sense of it... company_lookup is the string that is passed from the web form ("mono shop" in my example), company is a string that I am trying to find "mono shop" within (I am looping through every company in my csv). row[2] is the account number of a company that matches the "mono shop" string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to construct a regular expression to match the company name, and then use this regular expression to find the matched record.

```
company_lookup = company_lookup.split(" ").map{|r| Regexp.quote(r)}.join('.*?')

if company =~ /#{company_lookup}/i
  matches.push [row[2].to_s, company]
end
```

If performance is a big concern, or the data size is huge, you'd better try some full text search engine, such as [Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/)

Comment: Thank you, Arie Shaw. This makes sense and worked perfectly. Change made and pushed live. Thank you for the tip on Sphinx as well - if this csv gets much bigger I will give that a try.